# How to call mongoose static method using get router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have been trying to use a mongoose static method for my model to route it using get method but I can not find out how to do this.

**Here is my model written in JS:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const ShelterSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    address: {
        city: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        addressDetail: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    maxCapacity: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    residents: [{
        type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Survivor',
        autopopulate: {
            maxDepth: 1
        }
    }]
})

ShelterSchema.plugin(require('mongoose-autopopulate'))

ShelterSchema.statics.showAvailableShelters = function () {
    return ShelterModel.find({
        maxCapacity: { $gt: this.residents.length }
    })
}

const ShelterModel = mongoose.model('Shelter', ShelterSchema)

module.exports = ShelterModel
```

Here is the get router for show-available-shelters that I need to use my static method which I can not find out how:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const ShelterService = require('../services/shelter-service')

router.get('/all', async (req, res) => {
    const shelters = await ShelterService.findAll()
    res.render('shelter', { shelters })
})
router.get('/show-available-shelters', async (req, res) => {
    // res.send(availableShelters) ??
})
```

Also, I have ShelterService file which extends BaseService file:

```
const BaseService = require('./base-service')
const ShelterModel = require('../models/shelter')

class ShelterService extends BaseService {
    model = ShelterModel
}

module.exports = new ShelterService()
```

Base-service has functionalities in it.

Here is the module:

```
module.exports = class Service {
    async findAll() {
        return this.model.find()
    }

    async add(item) {
        return this.model.create(item)
    }

    async del(itemId) {
        return this.model.remove({ _id: itemId })
    }

    async find(itemId) {
        return this.model.findById({ _id: itemId })
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `ShelterService`?

Comment: `ShelterModel.showAvailableShelters() `

Comment: ShelterService is a file that extended from base-service which has all functionalities like findAll, add, delete or find. I should have added how it looks like though!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.